# How in Graylog to filter traceback messages from Python?

Tags: python, logging, trace, traceback, graylog

How to write a message search query in Graylog so that only traceback python is displayed?

The only messages needed are:

Traceback (most recent call last):

[image]

I haven’t tried anything since I don’t know.